# Accessing subviews delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

My Views Hierarchy is next:

1. My root View Controller that contains custom view
2. My custom UIView that contain custom UITableView
3. My custom UITableView

And i want to use delegate methods of my custom UITableView, but i don't really know how to access it's delegates because UITableView is added in my custom UIView class. *Please clear me up, i'm little confused about this question.*

**Here's my code:**

Adding my custom UITableView to UIView(i'm using [CollapseClick](https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick)):

```
-(void) initMehod{
    DetailsView *testView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailsView"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];

    test1View = testView;

    //collapse click init
    CGRect viewRect = [test1View frame];
    viewRect.origin.x = 10;
    test1View.frame = viewRect;

    [test1View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];

    self.myCollapseClick.CollapseClickDelegate = self;
    [self.myCollapseClick reloadCollapseClick];

    // If you want a cell open on load, run this method:
    [self.myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:0 animated:NO];
}
...
```

And i'm using [PagedFlowView](https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView) in my root View Controller to add CustomView:

```
- (UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView cellForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    mainDetailV = (MainDetailView *)[flowView dequeueReusableCell];

    if (!mainDetailV) {
        mainDetailV = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainDetailView"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];
        //mainDetailV.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
        mainDetailV.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }

    [usedViewControllers insertObject:mainDetailV atIndex:index];

    return mainDetailV;
}
```

Everything works perfectly, except i can't use my custom UITableView delegate (for example didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method).

**EDIT: I have fixed my problem, PagedFlowView actually handles tag gesture recogniser and overrides my custom tableView delegate methods.**

Similar question:

- [UITableView as a subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555921/uitableview-as-a-subview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your collapsable tableview abstracts tableview delegates (i.e its a wrapper).
It provides you with a method didClickCollapseClickCellAtIndex instead. Use that.

It seems to be that you have some problem in understanding delegation pattern. 
Avoid breaking the cascading effect of delegation pattern. It makes debugging easy
and helps to understand the flow of the code. Below diagram might help you to understand what I mean

[image: Delegation pattern]

Implement you didSelectRowAtIndexPath in custom view instead of rootViewcontroller.

```
// This is your custom view
-(id)init{
     ----
    self.myCollapseClick.CollapseClickDelegate = self;
     ----

}

//collapsable delegate
-(void)didClickCollapseClickCellAtIndex:(int)index isNowOpen:(BOOL)open {
  // you need to create your own custom view delegate with mehthod didSelectIndex:index
   [self.customViewDelegate didSelectIndex:index];
}
```

In your rootviewcontroller you need to do this

> customView.customViewDelegate = self;

```
-(void)didSelectIndex:(int)index{
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed my problem, i will accept your answer though. You helped me understand delegates model little more. If you're interested what was the problem, please check EDIT in my question. Thanks!